# не могу вставить slider-swiper в табы

Tags: javascript, html, css, tab

день, вечер, ночь)
Как сделать слайдер внутри табов, пытался вставить slider-swiper, но всё просто сломалось https://github.com/ackerman2002/solar
[image: Такой слайдер нужен]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не вижу проблемы. В каждую карусель добавил ещё слайдов, поменял текста на разные, чтобы наглядней было. При переключении табов карусели менялись. Карусели так же сохраняют своё положение при переключении табов, например, если в первой карусели остановиться на третьем слайде и переключиться на другой таб, то при возвращении на первый таб карусель будет на третьем слайде. Проект скачал по ссылке из описания выше.